# Soundcloud Widget not working

Tags: jquery, soundcloud

Ive been at it for a while now, and I'm not getting any further, I'm using Soundclouds developer's API to include a widget on a page:

Page: http://www.projectmusicfestival.com.au/-artists/sam_idols (please click on "View Tracks")

Resource: https://github.com/soundcloud/soundcloud-custom-player/downloads

The problem is it's not finding the ID of the track, on line 640 of sc.player.js it calls this:

```
trackId = $track.data('sc-track').id,
```

But the data source does not exist...

Has anyone run into this problem before?

Shannon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're looking at the documentation for the custom player (the old Flash widget). To get this sort of info and to be able to control the widget, use the [Widget API](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/html5-widget).

Comment: Thankyou, I realised as well that the URL I was specifying wasn't the API url either, so there was two problems already! All working now :D